# Flash control disabled on Nikon Z7 when attempting to use external flash

Tags: camera-settings, off-camera-flash, wireless-flash, phottix, nikon-z7

I have a Nikon Z7 and the following rented equipment:

- Nikon SB-910 flash unit
- Phottix Odin II Receiver for Nikon
- Phottix Odin II Flash Trigger for Nikon

The on-camera setup is working great, it's my first time using a speedlight and I'm delighted with the results (using TTL). The off-camera is giving me trouble from the very first step. I've attached, locked and opened all the devices, disabled Silent Photography, enabled Fill Flash and set the shooting type to Single Frame. Regardless, I can't seem to configure the Radio communication between the trigger and receiver, as the Flash control submenu appears disabled and it shows "This option is not available at current settings or in the camera's current state" when I try to click it.

What can I do to enable it? Is there a chance that the trigger and receiver are not compatible with my camera? Thanks!

Comment: Is shutter type (d5) set to **Mechanical shutter**?

Comment: @inkista, yes, it was previously on Auto, I've set it to Mechanical but it didn't solve my issue :(

Answer (score 4):

You cannot control the trigger/speedlight from the camera because only the SB300/400/500/5000 are compatible with the Z's "unified flash control."
https://onlinemanual.nikonimglib.com/z7_z6/en/11_on-camera_flash_photography_03.html

Also make sure you are not in H+ release mode. https://onlinemanual.nikonimglib.com/z7_z6/en/06_shooting_controls_04.html